# Добавление элемента из одного списка в другой

Tags: python

Есть такой код, и мне нужно чтобы в "product_bag" можно было добавить не любой элемент, а только тот, который находится в первом списке "shop", как сделать?

```
shop = ["Молоко", "Хлеб", "Масло", "Кефир", "Сахар", "Огурец", "Помидор", "Капуста", "Пельмени", "Яблоки"]
print("Сейчас в магазине такие продукты: ")
print(shop)

print("Что будете приобретать?")
product_bag = []
product_bag.append(input())
print("В вашей сумке теперь лежит:", product_bag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто помещаете ввод в переменную и потом проверяете, есть ли этот продукт в списке:

```
new_product = input()
if new_product in shop:
    product_bag.append(new_product)
    print("В вашей сумке теперь лежит:", product_bag)
else:
    print("Такой продукт не найден в магазине!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
shop = ["Молоко", "Хлеб", "Масло", "Кефир", "Сахар", "Огурец", "Помидор", "Капуста", "Пельмени", "Яблоки"]
print("Сейчас в магазине такие продукты: ")
print(shop)

shop = [item.lower() for item in shop]
print("Что будете приобретать?")
product_bag = []

item = input()

if item.lower() in shop:
    product_bag.append(item)
    print("В вашей сумке теперь лежит:", product_bag)
else:
    print("У нас нету: ", item)
```

эти строки

```
shop = [item.lower() for item in shop]
```

```
item.lower()
```

ставят все значения в нижний регистр чтобы не имело значение что вводить в `input`

Можно попробовать так:

```
if max(shop, key = lambda x: x in item.lower()):
```

Comment: ну вы заморочились настолько, что странно даже отсутствие в коде `trim` :)

Comment: @Zhihar знал бы о нем то добавил бы